# Prevent duplicate login using the same username in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm keeping track of my logged in users in my meteor app using a keepalive method that every logged in user calls every 5 seconds.

It updates a mongo collection that saves the user id with the "last seen" timestamp.

Up until I've updated Meteor to 0.6.5, to prevent someone from logging in using an already logged-in username I've added the following code to `password_server.js` file in the `account-password` pacakge:

```
var alreadyConnected=false;
    Meteor.call("isUserConnected", user._id, function(err, result) {
      alreadyConnected=result;
    });
if(alreadyConnected)throw new Meteor.Error(403, "User Already Connected");
```

right after:

```
 var user = Meteor.users.findOne(selector);
  if (!user)
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "User not found");
```

*isUserConnected was a method I've created in the server code that checks if the user sent his keepalive signal the past 5 seconds..

After the update, it stopped working and I no longer know how to edit the package file..

Answer (score 0):

Using a keepalive to keep track of whether a user is connected is inefficient. You can use my user-status package, which keeps track of connected sockets, for example:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

Second, allowing the client to make the determination of whether he should or shouldn't be allowed to connect is insecure (and among other things, causes latency and requires that all users be published to the client side.) You should do this by adding a new login handler on the server side that checks the username and if such a user is already connected, and rejects the login if so. See the below package for how to define new login handlers and call them from the client:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-accounts-testing

Answer (score 0):

Using the Meteor accounts you can use their official [logoutotherclients](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_logoutotherclients) method

> Log out other clients logged in as the current user, but does not log
>   out the client that calls this function.

*For example, when called in a user's browser, connections in that browser remain logged in, but any other browsers or DDP clients logged in as that user will be logged out.*

Note that: This has to be called from the client side, up to you if you need something stronger to be processed from the server side.